# Order by in Couchdb

Tags: database, view, couchdb

I have a couch database that contains a name and a country field and i have created a view that returns a count per country.

Map function:

```
function(doc) {
   emit(doc.country, 1);
}
```

Reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
   return sum(values);
}
```

The problem is that i need to make an "order by", in this case by the count, descending.
Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, with vanilla couchdb, you can't sort the value on the reduce function.

Cloudant, a couchdb hosted provider, offers "chained map reduce" which solves this problem. See http://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html

You could do a couple options, one is host your data on cloudant, or two replicate your local data to cloudant to query your order-by.

There is also this: https://github.com/afters/couch-incarnate which unfortunately I have not tried, but might fit for what you are trying to do.

Comment: There has also been this recent proposal to couchdb http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-dev/201301.mbox/%3CCACV2MxcybtnN_CrZsftw0iM9JNiLuqJs5QHaYZbh6efk0JHjyg%40mail.gmail.com%3E but it is only in discussion.